# What is the difference between these two php operators?

Tags: php, operators

What is the difference between these 2 PHP operators ?

The first one is `=` and the second one is `.=`.

Comment: Whoever marked this for closing as "unclear what you're asking" - really? It seems *very* clear to me. Why is "unclear" turning into a catch-all close reason?

Comment: this seems more like a google question. This answer can even be found on w3schools.com with almost no effort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a language's operators and can be easily googled.

Comment: enlighten me...what do you google, to get  an answer for the question, cos i tried that.

Comment: I googled "List of PHP operators" (https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=list%20of%20php%20operators) and, at least for me, the first result is http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

Comment: I guess the trick here is to know that google often removes punctuation and symbols from searches so `==` and `.=` in your search might not have been considered.  Oh, and you should probably also mention the language you searching about.

Comment: @Jules like it or not, there is a tendency to use "unclear" rather than voting as off-topic with a custom close reason. Because that requires typing, not clicking.

Answer (score 1):

They are both assignment operators.

= on it's own simply assigns a value to a variable, e.g.

```
$welcome = 'Hello';
echo $welcome;
```

Above would output 'Hello'.

.= will add the value onto the existing value of the variable, e.g.

```
$welcome = 'Hello';
$welcome .= ' Red Baron';
echo $welcome;
```

Above would output 'Hello Red Baron' (TIP: notice the space before the Red Baron in the second line above)

I hope that explains it a little better.  If not check out the link below to the PHP documentation.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: Thanks alot Zenith, it's very simple things like those that make it easier to understand programming. Yet there's an army of thumbdowners who contribute to the depression and sadness when it comes to programming.

Comment: @RedBaron you misunderstand why we downvote.  The reason content like this gets downvoted is to protect our other existing content.  This question's value is relatively low because the answer is easily found on google.  A lot of effort is put into keeping only high value questions on this site... which is why yours was downvoted.